# Image transitions with React useState

Tags: css, reactjs, image, react-hooks, css-transitions

Can I add transitions when changing `img src` using `useState()`?

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const images = [image1, image2];
```

```
<button onClick={()=>setIndex(1)}>Image2</button>
<img src={images[index]}/>
```

When press the button, the image changes as the `index` changes. But I want to add a transition here.

I tried `transition` with CSS but it didn't work. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a property style directly on the img tag:

```
style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      transition: 'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out',
      opacity: index === 0 ? 1 : 0,
    }}
```